# How are the Google Play Top Apps Evaluated?

Tags: android, google-play

I am wondering how Google Play roughly calculates what the top applications are. This is because I made an application and it is ranked at number 60 - 70, which is better than a lot of other apps that have a lot more downloads. Because of this, I was wondering how the applications are evaluated because it is clearly not just based on number of downloads.

I Googled around quite a bit but I couldn't find anything. Does anyone have any knowledge of how it is done? And based on what variables/information? (Daily Downloads? Total Downloads?)

This would be very interesting and beneficial to know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following factors are generally accepted as playing a major part in the ranking of apps on the Google Play store:

- Downloads - this includes both the total number and also momentum (e.g. daily downloads)
- App quality - including percentage of users who keep the app after installing it.
- Frequency of user interaction with the app
- Uninstalls
- Number and quality of ratings and comments
- Country
- Keyword density and relevance in the app's metadata (also ensuring that all of the details are filled in such as description and screenshots)
- Social media factors - e.g. how many times the app gets +1s on Google+
- Number of backlinks to the play store listing for the app

Source: https://getappcase.com/blog/app-stores/how-does-google-play-rank-mobile-apps

Comment: Thank you for that information and the link. I couldn't find that information from a google search. Its strange that my application is rated nr 60 in the games section even though it doesn't seem to meet all of those factors. Ill accept your answer as soon as possible.

Comment: Crossing certain thresholds for downloads (e.g. 50k, 100k) influences ranking.